# How to overwrite Codeigniter 3 route to show just name instead id and name

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

I need a little guidance here. I'm using Codeigniter 3.
Since it is MVC fw with segment routing,  I want to know how is possible to create custom route which will show just a `name` of record (it can be category, product, post etc..) returned from database instead of `id/name` when I need `id segment` to identify which record from database I need to return or preview by that `id`.

I will post some code example:

Controller

```
class Categories extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('CategoryM');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data = array(
            'category_list' => $this->CategoryM->listAll()
            );

        $this->load->view('test/category_list', $data);
    }

    public function preview()
    {
        $categoryId = $this->uri->segment(2);

        $data = array (
            'previewByCategory' => $this->CategoryM->previewByCategory($categoryId)
            );

        $this->load->view('public/preview_by_category', $data);
    }
```

Model

```
<?php

    class CategoryM extends CI_Model {

        public function listAll() {

            $query = $this->db
            ->select('*') 
            ->from('categories') 
            ->where('parentid', NULL, TRUE)
            ->order_by('name', 'asc') 
            ->get();

            if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $query->result();
            }else{
                return false;
            }

            public function previewByCategory($categoryId=''){

                $query = $this->db
                ->select( /* posts and categories data */ )
                ->from('categories')
                ->join('posts', 'posts.categoryID = categories.id', 'left')
                ->where('categories.id', $categoryId)
                ->get();
                if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
                    return $query->result();
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
```

View

```
<?php if($category_list):?>
    <?php foreach($category_list as $category):?>
        <h3> 
            <a href="<?php echo base_url() . strtolower(url_title($category->name) . '/' . $category->id);?>">
                <?php echo $category->name;?>
            </a>
        </h3>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

My Routes

```
// Category routes
$route['categories'] = 'categories/index';
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = 'categories/preview/$1';
```

What I want is instead of routes

```
www.mywebsite/categoryname/categoryid/
```

to display just

```
www.mywebsite/categoryname
```

which will list all products from that category group. But how to do this without id in url. I'm sorry if my question is too broad. Thank's in advance.

Comment: you can do this `categoryname` if those are unique only

Comment: How to You mean ? To  fetch data based on value of category name without id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter does not allow you to get database access in routes.
but you can create the database instance manually.

**routes.php**

```
$slug= ($this->uri->segment(1)) ? $this->uri->segment(1) : false;
if($slug){
  //include your database 
  require_once(BASEPATH."/database/DB.php");
  $db=& DB();
  $category = $this->db
              ->select('name') 
              ->from('categories') 
              ->where('parentid', NULL, TRUE)
              ->where('name',$slug)
              ->get()->row();
  if($category){
    //$category->name must be unique in database
    $route[$category->name] = 'categories/index';
  }

}
```

In Categories controller

```
class Categories extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('CategoryM');
    }

    public function index(){
      echo $category_name=$this->uri->segment(1);
    }
}
```

**URL**

> www.mywebsite/categoryname

```
//if categoryname exist in category
```

**output :**

categoryname

Comment: I was also about making custom slug with mixing id and name values, but never tried to load db in route, I would try this way. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First you have to add column to your category table say `url_title`, which is unique and validate as a URI. Then you have to modify your route.php

```
// Category routes
$route['categories'] = 'categories/index';
$route['(:any)'] = 'categories/$1'; // $1 pass the utl_title value to Categories/preview($url_title)
```

and your controller

```
public function preview($url_title=null) {
    $categoryId = $this->uri->segment(2);

    $data = array (
        'previewByCategory' => $this->CategoryM->previewByCategory($url_title)
        );

    $this->load->view('public/preview_by_category', $data);
}
```

and your model

```
public function previewByCategory($url_title=''){
    $query = $this->db
    ->select( /* posts and categories data */ )
    ->from('categories')
    ->join('posts', 'posts.categoryID = categories.id', 'left')
    ->where('categories.url_title', $url_title)
    ->get();
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I hope this would work for you. Please be carefull my posted code will have syntax errors because I did not tested it.